# iOS switching between audio & subtitle tracks added using ffmpeg

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, ffmpeg, multilingual

Edit: Title altered to reflect that the answer and comments by @llogan cover switching between both audio *and* subtitle tracks.

I have an `m.mp4` with English audio and want to add a second audio stream in Italian so that I can play either language using the iPhone. When I used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i m.mp4 -i ita.mp3 -c copy -map 0 -map 1 out.mp4
```

the output from `ffmpeg -i out.mp4` (see below) shows that a new audio stream is added, and I can switch between audio streams using the VLC player. Yet when I [transfer the video](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210611) to the TV app and play it on either MacOS or iOS it only plays the original English and I see no options to play other languages.

How do I get it to be able to switch between either audio on iOS?

Here is the output from `ffmpeg -i out.mp4:`

```
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 400x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 482 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 102 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.100
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (copy)
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like MP3 in MP4. Some players don't like that. Try AAC: `ffmpeg -i m.mp4 -i ita.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c copy -c:2 aac -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=ita -movflags +faststart out.mp4`

Comment: This worked beautifully. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it as the answer. Thank you! Both audio streams showed up in Quicktime and iOS. However, when I tried to add Italian and English subtitles  with the following command, the audiostreams no longer showed up in the final.mp4. Can you help me with my subtitle command? Thanks!                                        ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -f srt -i eng.srt -i ita.srt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ita final.mp4

Comment: For the subtitles command use `ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -i eng.srt -i ita.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ita final.mp4`. Note that mov_text support is not universal, so your player may not support it.

Comment: @llogan It worked again! After using both of your commands on the same video, I'm now able to use either Mac OS Quicktime or iOS to switch between 2 audio tracks and 2 subtitle tracks.Thanks again!

Comment: The two commands can be combined into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some players don't support MP3 in MP4. Try AAC:

```
ffmpeg -i m.mp4 -i ita.mp3 -map 0 -map 1:a -c copy -c:2 aac -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=ita -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```